# Extension of Alfresco - tomcat/shared/

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm making an extension (ALL-IN ONE Extension) for Alfresco that I install in Alfresco's and makes the modifications on folder's

> alfresco_install/tomcat/webapps/share and
>   alfresco_install/tomcat/webapps/alfresco

. Exists a way to change a file within the folder

> alfresco_install/tomcat/shared/

? I want to change `alfresco-global.properties` but in the extension to anyone that can install the extension have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to work on `/shared` folder.

When you install a module through the `apply_amps` script, it's enough to put your module alfresco-global.properties file in `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/<your-module-id>/alfresco-global.properties` and those settings will be picked up automatically